# Access Updating the Subform with Item selected in Listbox

Tags: ms-access, listbox, subform

I have the following code which does the following:
1. delete the data from a view table
2. Appends data from the main from to the main table
3. Selects ID & Product nr of the appended record and populates in the view table 
4. Clears the controls on the main form
5. Refreshes the form

Note: ID Listbox Rowsource is a Select ID query from the view table. Subform populates when I click on the ID from the listbox. However I would like it to prompt the subform to populate once the ID box is populated.

Problem: After appending the record, the ID listbox populates, it selects the item, however the subform (which is linked through Master - Child) does not requery with record data for the ID nr which is selected in the Listbox.

```
Private Sub cmdInsert_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
CurrentDb.Execute "delete from EC_ID_Table"
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("EC_Insert_New_Record")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("EC_ID_Table qry")
For Each ctl In Form_frmEC.Controls
Select Case ctl.ControlType
Case acTextBox
    If ctl.Name <> "ID" Then
        ctl.Value = ""
    End If
    Case acOptionGroup, acComboBox, acListBox
    ctl.Value = Null
Case acCheckBox
    ctl.Value = False
End Select
Next
DoCmd.SetWarnings (Warningson)
MsgBox "Insert Complete!"
Me.Form.Refresh
Me.ID.Selected(0) = True
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: @ WayneG.Dunn - please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the subform.  I think it goes like this:

```
Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form.Refresh
```

(changing the name of your Mainform and Subform1 where applicable).

Otherwise, you could try rebuilding the RecordSource:

```
Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
```

Comment: `.Refresh` only updates the current record, but if no record is loaded yet, `.Requery` must be used. I think.

Comment: @Andre451  from what I can see the frmEC_sub.Form.Requery refreshes the subform. However I have an impression that the subform Child field does not see the value stored in Master field. I have to click on it in order to populate the subform.

Comment: Problem solved - I added
Me.Form.Refresh
Me.ID.SetFocus
Me.ID.Selected(0) = True
frmEC_sub.Form.Requery
Thank you everyone!